# Scriptrunner - how to rename attachment filename

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

I am using scriptrunner 6.16.0 in JIRA 8.13.2. When a user attach a file when creating a new issue / edit existing issue in JIRA, I would like to rename the file.

I am trying to achieve this using scriptrunner using a validator (during transition). I was able to use *TemporaryWebAttachment* object to get the filename, but this value cannot be modified.

Any suggestion on how to rename this filename?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a new TemporaryWebAttachment with data from the original one and use that?

Comment: I was not able to get the file data stream from the original. Any idea how to get the stream from TemporaryWebAttachment ?